# $3$-letter, $3$-digit license plate but '$0$' and 'O' can't be used at same time

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**:

> A license plate contains a sequence of $3$ letters of the alphabet followed by a sequence of $3$ digits. How many different license plates can be produced if '$0$' and 'O' cannot be used at the same time?

**Video's approach**:

> Answer$=$Number of times '$0$' is not used$+$Number of times '$O$' is not used$-$Number of times neither '$0$' not 'O' is used. $\qquad$(Subtraction as it had been counted twice)
> $\Rightarrow \text{Answer}=26^3\times9^3+25^3\times10^3-25^3\times9^3$

**My Approach**:

> Answer$=$Total number of combinations$-$Undesired number of combinations
> $\Rightarrow \text{Answer}=26^3\times10^3-(26⋅26⋅3+26⋅3+1)(10⋅10⋅3+10⋅3+1)$
> Here a bracket's part is: There are 7 combinations of 'O' coming in 3 different places: $(O,-,-)(-,O,-)(-,-,O)(O,O,-)(-,O,O)(O,-,O)(O,O,O)$.
> The blank can be filled in $26$ ways. Similarly for $0$ too.

I get the video's approach. But I can't find mistake in my approach. Please help.

Comment: @AlvinL I feel bad. You are right. If you wish to post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept. If not, I'll delete the question.

Comment: @AlvinL thank you. what would you like me to do?

Comment: @AlvinL if you don't mind, if have posted an answer from your help. Please check. Venn diagram isn't needed.

Comment: Your modified approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AlvinL for pointing out my mistake.

The approach is correct except for a slight mistake:

> The blank can be filled in $\bf 26$ ways.

Well, you don't want to count 'O' again for the remaining blanks.
So the blanks can be filled in $25$ ways instead of $26$.
Similarly, for $0$, the blank can be filled in $9$ ways instead of $10$

$\Rightarrow \text{Answer}=26^3\times10^3-(25⋅25⋅3+25⋅3+1)(9⋅9⋅3+9⋅3+1)$

This is will give you the same answer as obtained by the video.

Comment: Indeed, your base types already cover the symbol $O$, so you don't need to count it again.

Comment: Your main lesson should be: double counting is fine if you are aware of it. Afterwards just subtract once what you have double counted and things are repaired. The video approach beats yours in clearness and elegancy. Promote it to be your approach from now on. Try to get familiar with the so-called "principle of inclusion/exclusion".

Comment: @drhab thanks a lot for the showing me better way. I thought that my approach is simpler (less complex). But now it feels rather crude. So I'll focus on video's approach (I wasn't seeing it's clarity or elegance before). And yes! your 1st sentence is exactly what video said.